# Pyspark efficient map-reduce algorithm to sort sub-lists in a distributed system

Tags: python, algorithm, apache-spark, mapreduce

Given an RDD:

```
+----------+----------+------------------------+
| a        | me       | [(1;1); (10;2); (5;3)] |
|          |          |                        |
| b        | dog      | [(1;3); (10;4); (2;4)] |
+----------+----------+------------------------+
```

I want the to map each row so that its subarrays are sorted by the keys (first element of each tuple) without using built-in Python functions, because those are not distributed functions. The size of sub-lists is also large. The sorted output will look like this:

```
+----------+----------+------------------------+
| a        | me       | [(1;1); (5;3); (10;2)] |
|          |          |                        |
| b        | dog      | [(1;3); (2;4); (10;4)] |
+----------+----------+------------------------+
```

You can treat the semicolons ";" as commas. They are used so the table generator I use doesn't split the array into pieces.

**RAW INPUT:**

```
(a,me,[(1,1),(10,2),(5,3)])
(b,dog,[(1,3),(10,4),(2,4)])
```

**RAW OUTPUT:**

```
(a,me,[(1,1),(5,3),(10,2)])
(b,dog,[(1,3),(2,4),(10,4)])
```

Currently I am using this along with a simple map() call to sort the sub-lists:

```
def sort_sublist(row):
    return (row[0], row[1], sorted(row[2], key=lambda tup: int(tup[0])))
...
my_rdd = my_rdd.map(lambda row: sort_sublist(row))
```

The function uses Python's sorted() function which isn't distributed. To make the map-reduce algorithm more efficient, I need to find a way to do what is done in the function above using Apache Spark's functions (map(), reduce(), etc).

**AN IDEA:**

I have done as far as the following pseudo-code:

```
[ (a,me,[(1,1),(5,3),(10,2)]),
(b,dog,[(1,3),(2,4),(10,4)]) ]

=> map =>

[ [(1,1),(5,3),(10,2)],
[(1,3),(2,4),(10,4)] ]

=> zipWithIndex =>

[ ([(1,1),(5,3),(10,2)], 0),
([(1,3),(2,4),(10,4)], 1) ]

=> flatMap =>

[ ( (0,(1,1)),(0,(5,3)),(0,(10,2)) ),
( (1,(1,3)),(1,(2,4)),(1,(10,4)) ) ]
```

Here is where I run into trouble. If I create unique string keys using string concatenation:

**TRY 1:**

```
=> map =>

[ (0+1,(1,1)),(0+5,(5,3)),(0+10,(10,2)),
(1+1,(1,3)),(1+2,(2,4)),(1+10,(10,4)) ]

=> key string concatenation =>

[ (01,(1,1)),(05,(5,3)),(010,(10,2)),
(11,(1,3)),(12,(2,4)),(110,(10,4)) ]

=> sortByKey =>

[ (01,(1,1)),(05,(5,3)),(010,(10,2)),
(11,(1,3)),(110,(10,4)),(12,(2,4)) ]
```

**ISSUE 1:** the order of the second row is not in order. If I create unique keys using integers:

**TRY 2:**

```
=> map =>

[ (0+1,(1,1)),(0+5,(5,3)),(0+10,(10,2)),
(1+1,(1,3)),(1+2,(2,4)),(1+10,(10,4)) ]

=> key integer sum =>

[ (1,(1,1)),(5,(5,3)),(10,(10,2)),
(2,(1,3)),(3,(2,4)),(11,(10,4)) ]

=> sortByKey =>

[ (1,(1,1)),(2,(1,3)),(3,(2,4)),
(5,(5,3)),(10,(10,2)),(11,(10,4)) ]
```

**ISSUE 2:** the order of rows is lost in the process.

The gist of the problem is finding a way to keep the order of the rows, while being able to provide each key within that row a value to sort by such that each row's tuple pairs is sorted by the tuple's key integer value. My approach may not be the solution. I am also new to Apache Spark, so hopefully someone with more knowledge of its inner workings can provide some insight on whether there is a way to achieve this.

Comment: Using `sorted` is as efficient as it gets here.

Comment: @zero323 would that still be true if the sub-lists is a few hundred in size?

Comment: It should be true at any scale at which keeping a single local list makes even remote sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been a long time since I worked in Spark, but from what I remember it's not a problem that `sorted` is not distributed, as it will be applied per RDD-partition when called inside `map()`.

Still, if you really want to avoid `sorted`, here's a rather clumsy approach that accomplishes your goal:

```
import pyspark
sc = pyspark.SparkContext() 

# load data
data = [('a','me',[(1,1),(10,2),(5,3)]),
        ('b','dog',[(1,3),(10,4),(2,4)])]
rdd = sc.parallelize(data)

# perform sorting
(rdd.map(lambda x: (x[0],x[1]))
    .zipWithIndex()
    .map(lambda x: (x[1],x[0]))
    .join(
        rdd.map(lambda x: x[2])
           .zipWithIndex()
           .flatMap(lambda x: [(x[1],y) for y in x[0]])
           .map(lambda x: (x[1][0], (x[1][1], x[0])))
           .sortByKey()
           .map(lambda x: (x[1][1], (x[0], x[1][0])))
           .groupByKey()
           .map(lambda x: (x[0], list(x[1])))
    )
    .map(lambda x: (x[1][0][0], x[1][0][1], x[1][1]))
    .collect()
)
```

It's the code inside the `join()` that does the sorting on the inner lists of tuples. The `join()` and surrounding code is used to connect the sorted tuples back to the string entries ('a', 'me', etc) that they started with.

**UPDATE**
In response to a comment question about efficiency, `sorted` is definitely faster than the solution I provided above.  Here's some sample data to demonstrate, with 10,000 tuples in the sub-lists:

```
import numpy as np
minval = 1
maxval = 11
N = 10000
tup_list1 = zip(np.random.randint(minval,maxval,N),
                np.random.randint(minval,maxval,N))
tup_list2 = zip(np.random.randint(minval,maxval,N),
                np.random.randint(minval,maxval,N))

data = [('a','me',tup_list1),
        ('b','dog',tup_list2)]
rdd = sc.parallelize(data)
```

Without sorted, using the approach described above:

```
%timeit (rdd.map(lambda x: (x[0],x[1]))
            .zipWithIndex()
            .map(lambda x: (x[1],x[0]))
            .join(rdd.map(lambda x: x[2])
                     .zipWithIndex()
                     .flatMap(lambda x: [(x[1],y) for y in x[0]])
                     .map(lambda x: (x[1][0], (x[1][1],x[0]))) 
                     .sortByKey()
                     .map(lambda x: (x[1][1], (x[0],x[1][0])))
                     .groupByKey()
                     .map(lambda x: (x[0],list(x[1]))))
                     .map(lambda x: (x[1][0][0], x[1][0][1], x[1][1]))
                     .collect())
```

Response:

```
# The slowest run took 25.94 times longer than the fastest.  
# This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
# 1 loop, best of 3: 1.18 s per loop
```

OP's original approach, using `sorted`:

```
%timeit (rdd.map(lambda x: (x[0],x[1], sorted(x[2], key=lambda tup: int(tup[0]))))
            .collect())
```

Response:

```
# 1 loop, best of 3: 193 ms per loop
```

Some speedup will be possible with careful use of `cache()`, but still, `sorted` is both the simpler and faster solution here.

This isn't really an excellent use case for the map/reduce paradigm; in my answer I kind of forced it.  Map/reduce is more powerful when there are many duplicate keys, and useful functions to apply for aggregating those keys' respective values.

Comment: The actual sub-lists contain a few hundred tuples, should I still use sorted() or your map reduce algorithm?

Answer (score -1):

If your looking for an algorithm to sort min to max

```
def sortList(x):
    currentlist = x
    newlist = []
    for i in range(len(currentlist)-1):
        newlist.append(min(currentlist))
    return newlist
```

I'm sorry if this wasn't of much help but I hope this helped!

Comment: This isn't a map-reduce algorithm, no better than what I have now.

Comment: Down-voted as not applicable to functional methods in Spark.